# What does it mean when Cinderella said "They treat me as well as they're able."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Cinderella 2015 horse chase scene, Cinderella said "They treat me as well as they're able." and the prince said "I'm sorry!"

What does it mean "as well as they're able" in the sentence?

Comment: Without having seen the movie or knowing the larger context, it sounds like she's saying: "My family treats me as well as they are able to treat me".  The prince's reaction suggests that they must be very ill-equipped to take care of her.

Comment: Do you have a link to the video? If so can you say at what minute it occurs?

Comment: If you are wanting more of the meaning behind the words, versus an explanation of the words themselves, it means something like, Cinderella's step-family is horrible, so she can only be treated horribly by them. Granted, I haven't seen the newest movie, so this is just conjecture from the fairy tale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"They treat me as well as they're able"

I'll break it down to you.

Cinderella is a completely kind person and being so pure-hearted, she respond that Her Step-Mother and Step-Sisters treat her well to an extent - Implying that they treat her bad but for Cinderella, they also treat her "good" in a certain way and so Kit said "I'm sorry".

Bottomline, Kit asked if She's being treated good but since Cinderella can't say that "No they abuse me, they're monsters", she simply explained that they "treat me good with their fullest capacity to treat people good"

Answer (score 2):

I would guess, not having seen the movie, that she means that they treat her as well as they are competent to (which is not very much).

Answer (score 1):

It means 'as well as they are able to treat me'.  'As well as they can treat me' or simply 'as well as they can' would also have had the same meaning.